# "Agradecer también...", "Concluir ya con...",

Tags: gramática

Es común escuchar todo tipo de discursos formales y presentaciones orales en que, como si fuese un recurso culto, se omite el verbo auxiliar en una perífrasis verbal, normalmente al inicio de una oración: "decir también que el aumento de los casos se debe...". Esta puede llegar a ser la estructura de la mayoría de las oraciones en algunos discursos, lo que hace que me suene especialmente incorrecta.

¿Es una estructura válida? ¿De dónde surge en caso contrario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comenzar una oración con un infinitivo es un error, salvo que el infinitivo sea sujeto de la oración. Supongo que el origen de este mal uso procede de sobrentender verbos conjugados como "Querría", "Me gustaría", "Estoy aquí para", "Es mi obligación", "No puedo menos que", etc.

En Internet hay algunas referencias a este error, pero no he encontrado ninguna en libros de gramática (tal vez, por lo elemental del error):

- [Fuente 1](https://www.meneame.net/m/corr%C3%ADgeme/comienzo-frases-infinitivo#:%7E:text=Usar%20el%20infinitivo%20para%20comenzar,bien%20hace%20dif%C3%ADcil%20su%20comprensi%C3%B3n.):

> Es común hoy en día empezar discursos literalmente así: "Bueno,
> agradecer a todos los presentes su asistencia a este acto...".
>
> Curiosamente, parece como si esa frase necesitara los tres puntos,
> porque le falta algo al final y necesitamos enunciarla con un énfasis
> suspensivo. En cualquier caso, de tanto usarla, ya es difícil explicar
> por qué esta construcción es tan aberrante.
>
> ¿Dónde está el sujeto en esa frase? Usar el infinitivo para comenzar
> una frase es un error grave, a no ser que ese infinitivo sea usado
> como sustantivo. Por ejemplo, sería correcto: "Agradecer a todos los
> presentes su asistencia es mi obligación". Esta forma discursiva es
> muy común al presentar noticias, si bien hace difícil su comprensión.
>
> Lo cierto es que a la frase inicial le faltan dos cosas: sujeto y
> verbo principal. Ambos parecen ser implícitos, pero su omisión no es
> retórica, sino que responde a pura vagancia, desidia o simple
> ignorancia. Así, lo correcto hubiera sido: "Bueno, (yo) quiero / debo
> / tengo que agradecer a todos los presentes su asistencia a este
> acto".

- [Fuente 2](https://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vCodigo=37939):

> El empleo cada vez más frecuente en los medios de comunicación de un infinitivo para iniciar un discurso hablado o escrito, se puede considerar incorrecto en casos como el que sigue: *En primer lugar, comentarles que no he podido venir antes porque me ha surgido un imprevisto. Este uso en el que se ha elidido el verbo principal responde probablemente a una cuestión de economía del lenguaje. Pero debemos tratar de evitarlo, puesto que entraña un empobrecimiento de nuestra lengua. Y es que, en español, la oración debe incorporar siempre que pueda una forma verbal conjugada, así en la frase anterior lo correcto hubiera sido que escribiésemos: En primer lugar, voy a (o tengo que, deseo, quiero...) comentarles que no he podido venir antes porque me ha surgido un imprevisto.

Answer (score 0):

**Me gustaría** añadir que, tras varias consultas, he visto que esto es el llamado [*infinitivo fático*](https://blog.lengua-e.com/2007/infinitivo-fatico-o-radiofonico/): uso del infinitivo como verbo principal y no como subordinado, que es como sería correcto.

**No me queda sino** agradecer, pues, la ayuda a las profes de [deletreando.es](https://deletreando.es/) con este error tan común hoy en discursos de incluso aquellos de quienes esperamos un buen uso de la lengua...