# "Relaciones sexuales" como sinónimo de encuentro o sesión individual

Tags: uso-de-palabras, expresiones, modismos

Está muy extendida, por no decir universalizada, esta expresión para referirse a encuentros aislados durante los que se ha tenido sexo. "Fulanito tuvo relaciones sexuales con él ayer". Siempre en plural o incluso como "tuvimos relaciones sexuales tres veces". Entiendo que esto es tan incorrecto como decir que la tarde anterior mantuviste una relación de amistad con un amigo con quien tuviste un encuentro, o que mantienes relaciones maternofiliales cada vez que ves a tu hijo o, como mucho, cada vez que le das a luz. ¿No debería funcionar "sexuales" aquí como adjetivo de un tipo de vínculo entre personas caracterizado por la actividad sexual entre ellos, así como una relación puede ser de amistad, laboral, etc.?

EDITADO:

Desde este punto de vista tampoco sería correcto "Fulanito tuvo una relación sexual con él ayer", dado el carácter durativo de "relación": entre un vendedor y un cliente la relación será comercial aunque no se esté dando en ese momento el acto o trato que le da carácter de mercantil.

Comment: 'su' relación es coloquial, 'una' relación como estándar .

Comment: No entiendo a dónde pretenden llegar ninguno de los comentarios. ¿Podrían elaborar un poco más la explicación?

Comment: ¿ Qual  es la pregunta ? Nadie ha respondido.

Comment: La pregunta es lo que va entre "¿" y "?", y se espera la justificación de la respuesta, claro. Como en este otro caso: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/37061/agradecer-tambi%c3%a9n-concluir-ya-con trato de averiguar si este uso tan extendido es correcto, aceptado, y su origen

Answer (score 2):

Es una expresión utilizada como sinónimo de "fornicar" o "copular", porque por alguna razón la gente siente que esas palabras suenan muy "fuertes" o explícitas. Existen otras expresiones que tampoco parecen correctas gramaticalmente como "hacer el amor" o "favores sexuales": el primero indica presencia de romance en el acto y el segundo suele denotar una forma de intercambio usualmente económico. "Relaciones sexuales" es una expresión neutra que no sugiere el motivo del encuentro.

Tal vez la razón por la que la expresión se estableció de esa manera sea debido a los orígenes católicos del idioma español, como una forma de censura ante los rumores de actos indecentes, en los que se sobreentiende que no es la primera vez que ha pasado. Esa expresión se usa casi exclusivamente en tercera persona.

Comment: Pero no se trata tanto de por qué se usa, sino por qué se usa de forma que, con otro tipo de relación sería incorrecta. Para lo mismo se puede decir, entiendo, que dos personas mantienen una relación sexual, puesto que tienen sexo a menudo, o para referirse a la cópula, simplemente que mantuvieron sexo o un encuentro sexual. Es decir, ¿se acepta y debería aceptarse como correcta la expresión, si no nos basamos en que, vale, se usa y por tanto a la larga lo aceptamos?

Answer (score 0):

Sólo estaba corrigiendo porque escribió tuvo su relación y eso suena a coloquial, borró el comentario.

Ahora sobre tu pregunta, deberías acotarla para ver si se enfoca exclusivamente en si su uso en plural y singular es perfectamente usable como adjectivo que califica a esa actividad, las cuales ambas se usan, o bien el problema es si es correcto o no para este tema en particular, porque también se puede decir que tal colega como tú mismo dices, partido, empresa, país u organización tuvo relaciones con otro/mantuvo una determinada relación con ... de tipo ... y no es incorrecto.

Lo otro es que hay un ligero matiz si se dice mantuvo, estuvo, tuvo, tiene o mantiene. También habría que preguntarse si es un calco del inglés had relations así mismo se diferencia de had sexual intercourse, de relationship(s), sexual relation y de to be tied up with, having sex o kept on going with etc y tal vez por eso hay espacio para esa particularidad.

O tal vez te preguntabas si es moralmente correcto o no.

O si debe ser exclusivamente o bien en plural o singular según tu perspectiva.